# How do I make ItemsControl to use different editors for different rows in the same column (depending on a data type)?

Tags: wpf, templates, binding, datatemplate, itemscontrol

I need to allow user specify filters applied to a search. I want UI to look something like this:

[image: different editors in the same column]
(in the picture above I manually typed "Test" and chose "Both" in ComboBox, actual binding doesn't work)

So, user could select which filters to apply and specify value using a corresponding editor (TextBox for strings, ComboBox for enums, etc).

To create this one I used DataGrid with TemplateColumn, DataTriggers and DataTemplates (it doesn't work completely as I need, that's why I'm writing this question):

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Value">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentControl>
                <ContentControl.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SearchFilter.Type}" Value="string">
                                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <TextBox Text="{Binding SearchFilter.Value}"/>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SearchFilter.Type}" Value="enum">
                                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{wpf:EnumMembers dataModel:MyEnumType}" SelectedItem="{Binding SearchFilter.Value}" />
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </ContentControl.Style>
            </ContentControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

The DataGrid is bound to a ViewModel containing a list of these filter objects:

```
public class PositionSearchFilter
{
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

The problem with this approach is data binding doesn't work inside DataTemplate (at least in my code, maybe I'm doing something wrong), I mean this part:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding SearchFilter.Value}"/>
```

Of course, I could manually create a bunch of controls (i.e. not using ItemsControl), but I want a generic solution, so I could simply take a list of filter objects and get a completely working UI.

Please help me solve my task.

Comment: Do you usually see the correct control but no data bound to it, or do you see nothing at all in the cell when you click to edit it? The first thing I noticed is this is a `CellTemplate`, not the `CellEditingTemplate`, which may be related. It's hard to tell without a better description of what is actually happening

Comment: Rachel, I see correct controls, but no data bound to it. So, Binding on DataTrigger itself works (and it sets correct DataTemplate), but inside that DataTemplate binding doesn't work.

Comment: I would suggest using a tool like [Snoop](https://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) to inspect the UI at run-time and take a look at what the DataContext is behind your `ContentControl`. My best guess is `ContentControl` is a special case where the DataContext of the ContentTemplate is set to the .Content property itself, which would explain why your binding was failing. If that is the case, binding the `.Content` property to the DataContext should fix the issue : `<ContentControl Content="{Binding }">`

Comment: @Rachel, I've used Snoop and it shows that ContentControl's DataContext is correctly set to an expected ViewModel. Inside that ContentControl there is ContentPresenter and inside it is my actual control (TextBox for example). Both ContentPresenter and actual control have Null as DataContext. If I set `<ContentControl Content="{Binding}"` then it works! ..but I don't understand why :(..

Comment: I think ContentControl is special in that the ContentTemplate has it's DataContext set to the `.Content` property, so you have to make sure that is set for the bindings in the ContentTemplate to show up correctly :)

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own [DataTemplateSelector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Controls.DataTemplateSelector(v=vs.110).aspx) that will decide which `DataTemplate` to use for which particular data type.

Here is an example of a `DataTemplateSelector`:

```
class ValueCellTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate StringTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate EnumTemplate { get; set; }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        if (item is PositionSearchFilter)
        {
            PositionSearchFilter element = (PositionSearchFilter)item;
            if (element.Value is string)
            {
                return this.StringTemplate;
            }
            else if (element.Value is MyEnumType)
            {
                return this.EnumTemplate;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

You can instantiate this selector in your resources, providing the corresponding `DataTemplate`s at the same time:

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <local:ValueCellTemplateSelector x:Key="ValueCellTemplateSelector">
        <local:ValueCellTemplateSelector.StringTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Value}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </local:ValueCellTemplateSelector.StringTemplate>
        <local:ValueCellTemplateSelector.EnumTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{wpf:EnumMembers dataModel:MyEnumType}" SelectedItem="{Binding Value}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </local:ValueCellTemplateSelector.EnumTemplate>
    </local:ValueCellTemplateSelector>
 </DataGrid.Resources>
```

Finally, just set this selector in your column:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn CellTemplateSelector="{StaticResource ValueCellTemplateSelector}"/>
```

Note that in my example, the `DataTemplate` will be choosen according to the actual object type contained in the `Value` property. So we don't need the additional `Type` property in the filter class. If it's important to you, just change the selector accordingly.

Comment: Be warned that a `DataTemplateSelector` does not respond to change events, so if the value you're basing the template on can change, the `DataTemplateSelector` will not re-evaluate the template to use on it's own.

Comment: @Rachel, that's true, maybe I should have asked OP whether this is of importance.

Comment: @dymanoid, Thank you very much for your help and priceless time! It works! I am ready to mark this as an answer, unless someone suggests maybe even easier/shorter solution?

Comment: Although, maybe it's good that we have actual code (not only XAML here), because it may provide additional type-safety or be useful during refactoring.

Answer (score 0):

If you're inside a DataTemplate you'll need to tunnel your way out a little. Try:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding SearchFilter.Value, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" />
```

This should force the binding to work its way up until it gets to something of type DataGrid, then use that control's DataContext as the context for the binding.

Comment: This could would most likely cause problems because it would change the DataSource of the binding to `DataGrid.DataContext`, which is not the item the row is representing.

Comment: Doesn't work for me :( I tried to specify AncestorType={x:Type ContentControl} (cuz using Snoop tool I saw that my TextBox/ComboBox get placed inside ContentControl which have correct DataContext set), but it didn't work either.

Comment: @Rachel The things you pick up! My approach here doesn't work, but not because it changes the DataSource. DataGridTemplateColumn isn't part of the logical or visual tree for DataGrid, so there's no RelativeSource to find. See: http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/

Answer (score 0):

DataGridTemplateColumn isn't part of DataGrid's logical or visual tree. To get around this and set a DataContext for binding within it you can use a binding proxy as described here: http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/

```
public class BindingProxy : Freezable
{
    #region Overrides of Freezable

    protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
    {
        return new BindingProxy();
    }

    #endregion

    public object Data
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(DataProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DataProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Data.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DataProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Data", typeof(object), typeof(BindingProxy), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
}
```

In your Control/Window Resources you then define an instance of the proxy:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <local:BindingProxy x:Key="proxy" Data="{Binding}" />
</UserControl.Resources>
```

And from your DataGridTemplateColumn you can reference the proxy for your binding:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding SearchFilter.Value, Source={StaticResource proxy}}"/>
```

Comment: This is used in cases where you want to bind a property of the `DataGridTemplateColumn` to the data itself, such as the `.Header` property. It would not apply in this case though since we are not using the DataContext within the `DataGridTemplateColumn` properties anywhere.

Comment: Rachel, just out of curiosity and to better understand how things work, could we somehow make this trick work in this case?